# psycpg2 Insert into fails

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, psycopg2

I got some python code (psycopg2) with which should insert data into a database:

```
def debug(self):
    try:

        self.connection.execute(
            "SELECT test();")
        res = self.connection.fetchall()
        print(res)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return
```

The test() function in pgsql is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
) RETURNS setof varchar
AS $Body$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Linie(name) VALUES('3');
    RETURN QUERY(SELECT * FROM linie);
END;
$Body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When i change the "name" value and execute the query in pgAdmin there is a now entry in the database. However when calling the function from python it always overrides the value.

The table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Linie(
name varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

For example with pgAdmin i can insert 1,2,3,4,5.
With python after running 5 equivalent queries it is just 5.

Calling the test function with nodeJS works fine.

When calling the function once from python then changing the insert value and then calling it from python  again, the values are not replaced but inserted.

Also it does not throw any errors and returns the table as it should (except the replaced value).
why is this happening and what can i do against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psycopg2 by default will not commit changes made to the database unless you explicitly call `connection.commit()` after executing your SQL. You could alter you code like so:

```
def debug(self):
    try:
        self.connection.execute(
            "SELECT test();")
        res = self.connection.fetchall()
        self.connection.commit()
        print(res)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return
```

However, please be careful doing this as I have no information on what exactly `self.connection` is an instance of, therefore I have assumed it to be of type `connection` :)
Alternatively, when you setup your connection to the DB, set the property `autocommit` to `True`, [as documented here.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) Example:

```
self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user='foo', password='bar', host='localhost', dbname='mydb')
self.connection.autocommit = True
```

If you are already using autocommit let me know and I'll have another look at your question.

Comment: not using commit was the problem thank you. and yes thats what i was using sorry for not clarifying.